# Finding a disk drive missing after a routine Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-update, troubleshooting, drive-letter

I just installed the latest Windows 10 update on my laptop, and my D: drive has disappeared. This is an internal hard drive where my Desktop, Downloads, and Documents drives all live, along with essentially all the work I have done in the last 20 years. (My C: drive is a solid state drive and is where windows and programs live).

The first sign of this was that Dropbox reported that the Dropbox directory had been moved or relocated. Windows explorer does not show the drive. If I click on Documents, which has been remapped to Drive D:, I get Windows error box "Location is not available. D::Documents is unavailable. If location is on this PC, make sure the device or drive is connected or the disk inserted, and then try again."

In the Device Manager, under disk drives only the SSD drive appears. In Control panel -> Disk Management, the drive does not appear in either the upper or the lower half of the panel. In the upper half, none of the unnamed partitions approaches the 1 TB size of the missing disk.

I have not been able to do any of the fixes I have found online because there is no driver to delete and reinstall, no offline disk to reset as online, no unnamed disk to assign a drive letter to.

Is it plausible that that this routine update somehow broke the physical connection to the drive? I am not a hardware guy,  but does it make sense for me to try opening up the laptop and unseating and reseating the drive?

Is there anything else I can do on the software side before I should take this to a repair shop?

Comment: I would take the drive to a local recovery agency and ask them for an assessment.

Comment: The failure is likely to be just coincidental, not related to the update. If you have a SMART utility, check its history for failure warnings. If not, then it can't check a drive it can't see, so John's idea of a data recovery company is a good one. A regular 'repair shop' would be no good for this task. Next time make backups, or you will again just be waiting for an accident to happen.

Comment: You have not taken backups for the last 20 years???

Comment: You may try to connect the drive with external USB enclosure. I had similar issues in the past and it helped.